# Anddroid TV - Date Picker

Tags: android, android-tv

I use standard Date picker for my Android TV app.
[image: Data picker]

But, i am unable to select wanted date number with D-Pad.
All i can do is change month and use Cancel/OK buttons.

Here is my code:

```
 public static class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


    public static Button button;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        Dialog dialog = null;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21)
            dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        else
            dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogTimeTheme, this, yy, mm, dd);

        return dialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);
    }

    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        //fragmentEPG.SendRequest(year, month, day, fragmentEPG._curentChannelID);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

    }
}
```

Comment: share your date selection code.

Comment: Hi @HemantParmar, i edit my question with code.

Comment: Any fix/solution on this? Did you use other library for date pick on TV App?

Comment: @ralphgabb In the end, we made our custom solution. I'm not sure if it's fixed in newer versions, after that.

Comment: @BrankoRiznić okay, yeah I also did create my alternative solution. Too bad this calendar widget is not yet supported with DPAD. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

The date picker, and likely the time picker, do not work with `Android TV` because you cannot pick dates with a **DPAD**. Moving up and down only scrolls through the calendar and left and right do nothing. Entering does not do anything either.

Comment: Hm, i am not sure that you understand my problem. I am actualy unabled to focus on mid part with numbers. I can only focus on OK/Cancel buttons.
On mobile or on TV with mouse works good. But on TV Box with D-pad -> NO.